# How to get the port number of client in rmi?

Tags: port, rmi

In RMI the server opens the registry on some port and then the clients connects to the server. Is there any way knowing on which port the connection is made between the server and the client?
I know the default port for RMI is 1099 but what is the port number on the client side? Does the client even opens a port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client does have a local port, as in any TCP connection, but there is no way for the server to discover it short of a custom socket factory.

There's also no reason for the server to need it. It's not a useful piece of information. It's not a listening port, so you can't connect to it; it changes from time to time; and it doesn't uniquely identify the client, because of client-side connection pooling and server-side idle connection timeouts.

Comment: I am making a chat application and at the client side I want to listen for incoming messages. The messages are passed to clients via server. So do I have to listen on the server port for incoming messages?

Comment: Make up your mind. Either you're using RMI or you aren't. If you are, you don't have to worry about ports at all beyond opening them in the server firewall. You won't be able to listen at the client side anyway due to client firewalls, NAT, or modems without port-opening facilities. You'll have to poll.

Comment: So which is a better approach? RMI or socket?

Comment: Could you explain why you think "There is no reason for the server to need it". What can I do if I want to keep my rmi sessions by socket not not address, because there are can be situations when different clients have the same address (for example they are behind one nat).